# SQL: Count Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT Impressions.Campaign_id as C_id, Verticals.Vertical_Name as V_name
FROM Impressions
Inner Join Verticals ON Impressions.Campaign_id = Verticals.Campaign_id;
```

The above query generates the result as:

```
   C_id            V_name
    ID1            Travel
    ID2            Retail
    ID3             Demo
    ID4             Demo
    ID5            Travel
    ID6             Demo
```

I want it to return the count of the number of occurances of the Vertical_Name column. In this case the result should look like :

```
V_id   Count
Demo     3  
Travel   2
Retail   1
```

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`COUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx), not `MAX` and to [`GROUP BY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) then vertical name:

```
SELECT Verticals.Vertical_Name as V_name, COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM Impressions
Inner Join Verticals ON Impressions.Campaign_id = Verticals.Campaign_id
GROUP BY Verticals.Vertical_Name
```